# Convert a string Id to unique Guid (or from md5 to Guid)?

Tags: c#, algorithm, md5, guid

I would like to create a system to convert an existing id (integer id or custom string id)

I would like to create a helper or extension method that generate a Guid from any int, long or string value. The idea is to update a database but keep some tracking from my old database. Each time I convert a string id like "O-2019-10-15" the system generate the same unique Guid. Let's focus on string here.

```
    public static Guid GenerateGuid(string input)
    {
        // Convertion
        byte[] _byteIds = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

        //What about using MD5?
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider _md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] _checksum = _md5.ComputeHash(_byteIds);

        // Convert ?
        string part1 = /* ??? */;
        string part2 = /* ??? */;
        string part3 = /* ??? */;
        string part4 = /* ??? */;
        string part5 = /* ??? */;

        //Concat these 4 part into one string
        return Guid.Parse("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}", part1, part2, part3, part4, part5);
    }
```

What do you think? Is md5 a correct start? Is there any rule in Guid() representation?

The idea of md5 is that I can convert everything to a 16 byte signature. From there I just need to convert it as Guid(). But I don't know the details about the Guid. Is there any rules already existing, reserved position for any data or other information?

Comment: I can not think of a sensible way to generate one Primary Key value from another Primary key value. Usually you just import, and let the target DB deal with creating that Auto-value. As for hash, that will be a seperate post.

Comment: It seems Guid and MD5 are both 16 bytes

Comment: With every Hash Function you inherently have the danger of hash colissions - two inputs resulting in the same output. When using a hash for comparision, you can only use it for quick "not the same" filtering. Even if two hashes match, you have to make a full comparision to verify that it is not just a hash colission. Considering that Hash functions have a variable input, but fixed output lenght, there is no way to avoid this. So you will have to deal with colissions happening.

Comment: You won't be able to guarentee uniqueness with that approach.  I don't know why you just don't use `Guid.NewGuid()`

Comment: @Christopher "With every Hash Function you inherently have the danger of hash colissions". Yes I know. Same with the Guid.NewGuid() in fact. But this is a risk I can take. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @MickyD I'm using Guid.NewGuid(). My question is if you cannot use Guid.NewGuid() and you must generate the Guid from a string or md5 value is there any rule to do it.

Comment: And If you all think I should not generate a Guid manually like this. Why? this is actually the most important point. Why. Only the risk of collision? If this is only that this is not a good reason. Everyone can evaluate the risk for his project.

Comment: @BastienVandamme: Because manual created tends to mess up the *Unique* part of "Globally Unique IDentifier." If you want just a certain size interger, that is doable. But that int will not be unique. At the end of the day, it sounds like you want a simple Integer. Not a integer with specific secondary properties.

Comment: This makes little sense. I can start with a string like "ABC", take its SHA-1 hash and magically convert it to 160 bits. But, in real life, it only has as much entropy as a three character string (perhaps 15 bits). Theres no way that's "globally unique". Yes, you can take 120-something bits, and squish it into one of the GUID schemes. But it's still just a bunch of bits with little entropy and it's definitely not a GUID

Comment: According to documentation on Wikipedia and other blogs since version 4 there is no garantie of Unique part and the risk of collision is considered. No, of course I will never convert a string like ABC to a Guid but I can translate a more sophisticate string to a Guid. What I want is the garantie in uniqueness into my environment. Sure I must prefix all my string with a kind of namespace.

Comment: Not a problem, I just thought you were after uniqueness.  Thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it like this.

I would use `Guid.NewGuid()` for new id and then keep the old id alongside it (or in a translation table).

Next time I need the new id I would look for the old id and see if I already have a guid for it.

---

If it is critical to keep one Id, which I don't recommend, I would have it as a `$"{guid}+{oldid}"`.

Comment: This is good practice but this is not answering to the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I did this

```
Guid GenerateGuid(string input)
{
    byte[] _byteIds = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

    MD5CryptoServiceProvider _md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] _checksum = _md5.ComputeHash(_byteIds);

    //Convert checksum into 4 ulong parts and use BASE36 to encode both
    string part1 = BitConverter.ToString(_checksum, 0, 4).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    string part2 = BitConverter.ToString(_checksum, 4, 2).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    string part3 = BitConverter.ToString(_checksum, 6, 2).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    string part4 = BitConverter.ToString(_checksum, 8, 2).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    string part5 = BitConverter.ToString(_checksum, 10, 6).Replace("-", string.Empty);

    return Guid.Parse($"{part1}-{part2}-{part3}-{part4}-{part5}");
}
```

To avoid collision the input must be unique too in my environment. I will prefix it with a namespace.

Comment: Why use `Guid.Parse`, when you could use the `Guid` constructor that takes a byte array `new Guid(_md5.ComputeHash(_byteIds));`

Answer (score -1):

Creating deterministic UUIDs based on an existing namespace is exactly what UUIDv3/v5 are intended for. However, first you will need a namespace UUID.

A convenient (and valid) way to accomplish this is hierarchical namespaces. First, use the standard DNS namespace UUID plus your domain name to generate your root namespace:

Guid nsDNS = new Guid("6ba7b810-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8");

Guid nsRoot = Guid.Create(nsDNS, "myapp.example.com", 5);

Then create a namespace UUID for your string:

Guid nsFoo = Guid.Create(nsRoot, "Foo", 5);

Now you're ready to use your new Foo namespace UUID with individual names:

Guid bar = Guid.Create(nsFoo, "Bar", 5);

The benefit of this is that anyone else will get completely different UUIDs than you, even if their strings (other than the domain, obviously) are identical to yours, preventing collisions if your data sets are ever merged, yet it's completely deterministic, logical and self-documenting.

(Note: I've never actually used C#, so if I got the syntax slightly wrong, feel free to edit. I think the pattern is clear regardless.)

Comment: I cannot find any `Guid.Create()` method in .NET.